# Calling terminal from shell scripts to display results of commands

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote a script to call terminal and run a series of commands. The terminal comes up but no result of the other commands.
I named the file **show-services-status.sh** dropped it in the home directory and made it executable using `chmod +x`

**show-services-status.sh** contain the following commands:

```
gnome-terminal
echo "Display Manager Status"
sudo systemctl status display-manager.service
echo "System Log Status"
sudo systemctl status syslog.service
```

1. Why does the terminal comes up without showing the result of the other commands?
2. I started terminal manually and executed `bash show-services-status.sh` it worked but i have to press q on the keyboard before i see the result of the next command. how can this be eliminated?
   thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. because all the commands are being run sequentially in the same shell from which you execute the `gnome-terminal` command - rather than running *inside* the new `gnome-terminal`
2. you can add the `--no-pager` option to the `systemctl` commands - see `man systemctl`

If you want to run the following commands inside the new `gnome-terminal`, you could wrap them in a shell and pass them as a command string, like:

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c '
  echo "Display Manager Status"
  systemctl --no-pager status display-manager.service
  echo "System Log Status"
  systemctl status syslog.service
'
```

Note that I omitted `--no-pager` on the final `systemctl` command in order to hold the terminal open - otherwise it will likely close immediately, before you have time to read the results.

Answer (score 0):

You may want this:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'echo "Display Manager Status"
systemctl --no-pager -l status display-manager.service 
echo "System Log Status"
systemctl --no-pager -l status syslog.service
read'
```

Press return to quit terminal.

If you use `xfce4-terminal` instead, you can use `-H` option before `-x` to make terminal wait, and no need to use `read`.

Comment: Does it work better than the code in the accepted answer?